# MySQL: Combine Multiple Calculated Fields

Tags: mysql, concatenation, calculated-columns

Having an issue combining multiple calculated fields...

Table (Simplified)

```
tblHVSR
+--------+-------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| hvsrID | hvsrChildID | hvsrParentID | hvsrDateOfContact | hvsrDaysParentReadWithChild |
+--------+-------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| autoIn | smallint    | smallint     | date              | smallint                    |
+--------+-------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Objective is to build one report with 4 calculated columns for averages (labels shown for clarity, don't match query headers currently:

```
+-------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Child | Parent | 1MonthAvg | 3MonthAvg | 6MonthAvg | 1YearAvg |
+-------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

After much internet scouring, I have tried things like:

```
select q1.hvsrChildID as CID, q1.hvsrParentID as PID, q1.avg as avg1, q2.avg as avg2,
a3.avg as avg3, q4.avg as avg4 from (select hvsrChildID, hvsrParentID, 
avg(hvsrDaysParentReadWithChild) as AVG from tblHVSR where hvsrChildID in
((select rosterChildID from tblRoster where rosterChildActiveYN = 1)) and
hvsrDateOfContact BETWEEN curdate() - interval 1 month AND curdate() group by hvsrChildID)
as q1 LEFT JOIN (select hvsrChildID, hvsrParentID, avg(hvsrDaysParentReadWithChild) as AVG
from tblHVSR where hvsrChildID in ((select rosterChildID from tblRoster where
rosterChildActiveYN = 1)) and hvsrDateOfContact BETWEEN curdate() - interval 3 month AND
curdate() group by hvsrChildID) as q2 LEFT JOIN (select hvsrChildID, hvsrParentID,
avg(hvsrDaysParentReadWithChild) as AVG from tblHVSR where hvsrChildID in
((select rosterChildID from tblRoster where rosterChildActiveYN = 1)) and
hvsrDateOfContact BETWEEN curdate() - interval 6 month AND curdate() group by hvsrChildID)
as q3 LEFT JOIN (select hvsrChildID, hvsrParentID, avg(hvsrDaysParentReadWithChild) as AVG
from tblHVSR where hvsrChildID in ((select rosterChildID from tblRoster where
rosterChildActiveYN = 1)) and hvsrDateOfContact BETWEEN curdate() - interval 1 year AND
curdate() group by hvsrChildID) as q4;

SELECT * FROM (select hvsrChildID, hvsrParentID, avg(hvsrDaysParentReadWithChild) as AVG1
from tblHVSR where hvsrChildID in (select rosterChildID from tblRoster where
rosterChildActiveYN = 1) and hvsrDateOfContact BETWEEN curdate() - interval 1 month
AND curdate() group by hvsrChildID) A, (select hvsrChildID, hvsrParentID,
avg(hvsrDaysParentReadWithChild) as AVG2 from tblHVSR where hvsrChildID
in (select rosterChildID from tblRoster where rosterChildActiveYN = 1) and
hvsrDateOfContact BETWEEN curdate() - interval 3 month AND curdate() group by hvsrChildID)
B, (select hvsrChildID, hvsrParentID, avg(hvsrDaysParentReadWithChild) as AVG3 from
tblHVSR where hvsrChildID in (select rosterChildID from tblRoster where
rosterChildActiveYN = 1) and hvsrDateOfContact BETWEEN curdate() - interval 6 month AND
curdate() group by hvsrChildID) C, (select hvsrChildID, hvsrParentID,
avg(hvsrDaysParentReadWithChild) as AVG4 from tblHVSR where hvsrChildID
in (select rosterChildID from tblRoster where rosterChildActiveYN = 1) and
hvsrDateOfContact BETWEEN curdate() - interval 1 year AND curdate() group by hvsrChildID) D;

select a.childID, b.parentID, concat_ws(' ', a.childFName, a.childLName) as CNAME,
concat_ws(' ', b.parentFName, b.parentLName) as PNAME, (select
avg(d.hvsrDaysParentReadWithChild) as avg1 from tblHVSR d where d.hvsrChildID = a.childID
and hvsrDateOfContact BETWEEN curdate() - interval 1 month AND curdate()) as AVG1 from
tblChildren a, tblParents b where a.childID in (select c.rosterChildID from tblRoster c
where c.rosterChildActiveYN = '1') and b.parentID in (select c.rosterParentID from
tblRoster c where c.rosterChildActiveYN = '1' and c.rosterParentActiveYN = '1') and
a.childParentID = b.parentID;
```

Clearly, I am lost here and it's only getting worse.  Can someone help me out with this, please?

Comment: your query is too long and not in managed format .can you please break it in parts with proper formatting . That ll be easy to understand

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query